# Why do we measure \$I_{ds}\$ for CMOS instead of \$I_{sd}\$?

Tags: cmos

The standard way to write current across a MOS seems to be along the \$I_{ds}\$, i.e. from drain to source. Why don't we use \$I_{sd}\$ instead? I understand both ways are equivalent, but would it not be more natural to think of current as flowing from the source to the drain?

Comment: If you want to type an inline equation for Mathjax, do `\$ YOUR EQUATION \$` instead of `$ YOUR EQUATION $`... I know, it's weird and we're probably the only StackExchange website that does it this way, but that's just how it is.

Comment: @KingDuken Beat me to it!

Comment: @awjlogan Enjoy your two points lol... But back to the question... I don't think I've ever seen a notation of \$I_{SD}\$ or \$I_{DS}\$... I mean, I've seen \$I_D\$ and \$I_S\$... Perhaps this is because you're not measuring some sort of "current potential" between two points... That wouldn't make sense. Perhaps you're thinking of voltage instead? \$V_{DS}\$ and \$V_{SD}\$? Those two I have seen before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The standard way to write current across a MOS seems to be along the
>   \$I_{ds}\$, i.e. from drain to source.

Let's pick at that statement: -

1. Current is not "across" something but voltage is
2. Current is through something but voltage isn't
3. Current is best defined as into a node or from a node

Given the above, EEs talk about \$I_{D}\$ or \$I_{S}\$ but not \$I_{DS}\$

> but would it not be more natural to think of current as flowing from
>   the source to the drain?

If the current is the same then it doesn't matter but it's not the same for (say) a bipolar transistor because the base takes current and \$I_{E}\$ is not the same as \$I_{C}\$.

So should we change this well formulated way of stating things specifically for MOS devices? No we shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In general, \$I_{D}\$ (my opinion), is better understood for an NMOS device as a positive value. For example, if you are using an NMOS as a switch, and you defined the current in the following direction, you get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEsetF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which will result in a *positive* value for \$I_D\$. Now, if were to use a PMOS as a switch, \$I_D\$ will typically flow in the opposite direction, that is why datasheets define \$I_{D}\$ as a *negative* quantity for PMOS devices (and in school, sometimes, you use [absolute values (take a look at this)](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/sp08/discussions/pmos) so that you don't have to worry about signs).

As mentioned in one of the comments, it seems like you may be thinking about voltages \$V_{DS}\$ or \$V_{SD}\$ but even those, are usually addressed by either using a positive value for \$V_{DS}\$ (for an NMOS), and a negative value for \$V_{DS}\$ (for a PMOS, or equivalently, positive \$V_{SD}\$) or you can use absolute value convention for those as well.

Hopefully that addresses your question.